# Is the category of monoids cartesian closed? Why?

Tags: category-theory, monoid

> Is the category of monoids cartesian closed? Why?

I read Steve Awodey's "Category Theory", and could not solve the exercise in chapter 6, stated above.

Here I speak of the "category of monoids" as the category with objects monoids and arrows homomorphisms between monoids.

Comment: Did you read the links you were given [at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/230539/11640)?

Comment: I read your comment, but still cannot understand this part: $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)\cong\mathcal{C}(1,Y^X)$. Why they are isomorphic?

Comment: @yrZhang $X\cong 1\times X$, and the condition of cartesian-closed categories requires $C(A\times B,C)\cong C(A,C^B)$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you! I see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever a non-trivial category is cartesian-closed, the final object $1$ cannot also be an initial object.

Otherwise:

$$\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(1\times A,B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(1,B^A)\cong\{\cdot\}$$

That is, every hom set would have to be a singleton.

Answer (score 6):

If $M$ is a non-trivial monoid, the functor $M \times - : \mathsf{Mon} \to \mathsf{Mon}$ doesn't preserve the initial object, and hence it cannot have a right adjoint.

Comment: You may be correct but I don't learn "adjoint" from now on. But I can understand Thomas Andrews's and Lin's answers without using adjoint.

Comment: Show that in any cartesian closed category, $X \times 0 = 0$ where $0$ denotes an initial object. You can prove this directly with any definition of "cartesian closed". More generally, you may show $X \times \coprod_{i \in I} Y_i \cong \coprod_{i \in I} X \times Y_i$. The statement about initial objects is the special case $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you so much. But Thomas Andrews's answer is more clear for me at least by now.